# Preorder insertion

Tags: algorithm, tree, insertion, preorder

I need to implement an n-ary tree. The problem is I'm allowed to use only preorder traversal. What I find it hard is to make a function that will add new node. New nodes are being added from left to right, and again, I'm not allowed to use level order, only preorder. 
What I thought is to maybe somehow compare levels of the leaf nodes, and if there are free nodes at the maximum level of the tree, then that's where I add new node. Since this is not that easy, and I'm not sure if I'm even on the right way, I decided to post question here to see if anyone has any idea? Or maybe if there's another way of doing this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I still haven't written the actual code, but I'm not asking you to do it either. Since I need an effective way to do this, I need ideas how to do it. So I'd be grateful if you helped me, instead of judging me cause I asked for help, NOT TO DO MY HOMEWORK. And if you read the post more carefully you'll see that I wrote what my idea was. Thanks.

Comment: A tree is a **very** general data structure. Even a linked list is (in a sense) a type of tree. 
Do you have specifications for how the tree should be implemented? is it a binary tree? does it have to be balanced?